# Obtaining a research paper's content using Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to obtain the contents of [this research paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.2763) using the requests library as follows:

```
data = requests.get('https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.2763#Sec1')
content = data.content
```

When I do this, I only get the section with the abstract. So I tried navigating to a random section by using the menu option on the right and I got the following link for the Results section of the paper:
`https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.2763#Sec2` (it appends a #Sec2 at the end as you can see)

Trying again with this link, I get the same results as before (only get the abstract content). How can I get all of the contents?

Comment: The paper seems to be [behind a paywall](https://i.imgur.com/ol1T7yP.png) (when I open it in the browser). Do you have an account on that website? Do you see the full paper when you open the page in the browser? Also, for requests, the part after the `#` in the URL is called a fragment and is not part of the request. So it does not affect the page content you're getting.

Comment: @Aziz Oh I see yeah I just noticed I'm logged into my university account. Is there a way to somehow provide the authentication from requests' side? Or how can I deal with this?

Comment: If the authentication is cookie based, you could find the cookie for your session and include it in the request: https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: Otherwise, you could emulate the login using a dedicated scraping library like Scrapy: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login

Comment: Glad to help! :-)